# Error when sending a message to telegram chat using Python Telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient


client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
async def main():
    await client.send_message(chat_id, 'Hello')


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When I try to run the code I get an error:

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChatIdInvalidError: Invalid object ID for
> a chat. Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure
> that the request is designed for chats (not channels/megagroups) or
> otherwise look for a different one more suited\nAn example working
> with a megagroup and AddChatUserRequest, it will fail because
> megagroups are channels. Use InviteToChannelRequest instead (caused by
> SendMessageRequest)

Chat's ID is correct, I checked. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is the account you are using already inside the channel/group?

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to confirm from your chat id and make sure you passed the correct id of your chat. you can use "@_Chat_ID" or use "htttp//t.me/Chat_link"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).